# Let $(f_n)$ be a pointwise bounded sequence of l.s.c. convex functions. Then $(f_n)$ has a convergent subsequence

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, uniform-convergence

**Disclaimer:** This thread is meant to record. See: [SE blog: Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and [MSE meta: Answer own Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4680/79762). Anyway, it is written as problem. Have fun! :)

---

Let $C$ be an open convex subset of a Banach space $X$ and $\mathcal F$ a collection of real-valued continuous functions on $C$. We say that $\mathcal{F}$ is *pointwise bounded* if, for each $x \in C$, the set $\{f(x) \mid f \in \mathcal{F}\}$ is bounded.

> **Theorem:** Assume $X$ is separable. Let $(f_n)$ be a pointwise bounded sequence of l.s.c. convex functions on $C$. Then there exists a subsequence $(f_{\varphi(n)})$ of $(f_n)$ that converges pointwise and uniformly on compact subsets to a continuous convex function on $C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need the following lemmas.

[*Lemma 1:*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4457698/if-mathcalf-is-pointwise-bounded-then-mathcalf-is-locally-equi-lipsch) Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of l.s.c. convex functions on $C$. If $\mathcal{F}$ is pointwise bounded, then $\mathcal{F}$ is locally equi-Lipschitz and locally equi-bounded.

[*Lemma 2:*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4457958/how-to-prove-that-the-convergence-of-f-n-is-uniform-on-compact-sets) Let $(f_{n})$ be a sequence of l.s.c. convex functions on $C$ that converges pointwise on $C$ to a (convex) function $f: C \to \mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is continuous and the convergence is [uniform on compact sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence#Definition).

Let $D$ be a countable dense subset of $C$. By [diagonal argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4459245/is-there-sigma-infty-such-that-sigma-infty-is-a-subsequence-of-sigma-n), we can extract a subsequence $(f_{\varphi(n)})$ such that $(f_{\varphi(n)}(x))$ is convergent for each $x \in D$.

Fix $a\in C$ and $\varepsilon>0$. By *Lemma 1*, $(f_n)$ is locally equi-Lipschitz, so there is $r,L>0$ such that $f_n$ is $L$-Lipschitz on $B(a, r) \subset C$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. There is $b \in D$ such that $\|b-a\| < \min\{r, \varepsilon /(2L)\}$. There is $N\in \mathbb N$ such that
$$
|f_{\varphi(n)} (b) - f_{\varphi(m)} (b)| < \varepsilon \quad \forall m,n>N.
$$

It follows that for all $m,n>N$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
|f_{\varphi(n)} (a) - f_{\varphi(m)} (a)|  &\le |f_{\varphi(n)} (b) - f_{\varphi(n)} (a)|  +|f_{\varphi(m)} (b) - f_{\varphi(m)} (a)|  +|f_{\varphi(n)} (b) - f_{\varphi(m)} (b)|  \\
&\le L\|b-a\|  +L\|b-a\|  + \varepsilon  \\
&\le 2L  \varepsilon /(2L)+ \varepsilon = 2\varepsilon.  \\
\end{align}
$$

It follows that $(f_{\varphi(n)}(a))$ is Cauchy and thus convergent. The rest then follows from *Lemma 2*.