# A characterization of $f \in L^1 (\Omega)$ by duality

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$ and $f \in L^1_{\text{loc}} (\Omega)$. I'm trying to do below exercise, i.e.,

> Prove that $f \in L^1 (\Omega)$ IFF
> $$
> A := \sup \left \{\int f \varphi : \varphi \in \mathcal C^\infty_c(\Omega) \text{ s.t. } \|\varphi\|_\infty \le 1 \right\} < \infty.
> $$
> If $f \in L^1 (\Omega)$ then $A = \|f\|_1$.

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

1. First we assume $f \in L^1 (\Omega)$. We define a linear map $T:L^\infty (\Omega) \to \mathbb R, \varphi \mapsto \int f \varphi$. Then $T$ is continuous w.r.t. the norm topology of $L^\infty (\Omega)$. We have
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   \infty > \|f\|_1 = \|T\|_{L^\infty (\Omega)^*} &:= \sup \left \{ T\varphi : \varphi \in L^\infty(\Omega) \text{ s.t. } \|\varphi\|_\infty \le 1 \right\} \\
   &\ge \sup \left \{T\varphi : \varphi \in \mathcal C^\infty_c(\Omega) \text{ s.t. } \|\varphi\|_\infty \le 1 \right\} \\
   &= A.
   \end{align*}
   $$
2. Now we assume $A < \infty$. Let $B_n := B(0, n)$ be the open ball centered at $0 \in \mathbb R^d$ with radius $n>0$. Then
   $$
   \|f\|_1 = \int |f| = \lim_n \int_{B_n} f \operatorname{sgn} f.
   $$
   Notice that $f \in L^1 (B_n)$ and $\operatorname{sgn} f \in L^\infty (B_n)$.  Fix $\varepsilon >0$. I already [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4676191/there-is-u-n-subset-mathcal-c-c-infty-omega-such-that-u-n-to-u-a) that there is $\varphi_n \in \mathcal C_c^{\infty} (B_n)$ such that $\|\varphi_n\|_\infty \le \|\operatorname{sgn} f\|_\infty \le 1$ and $|\int_{B_n} f \operatorname{sgn} f - \int_{B_n} f \varphi_n | < \varepsilon$. We define $\overline{\varphi_n} : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ by $\overline{\varphi_n} (x) := \varphi_n(x)$ if $x \in B_n$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $\overline{\varphi_n} \in \mathcal C_c^{\infty} (\Omega)$ with $\operatorname{supp} \overline{\varphi_n} \subset B_n$. It follows that $\int_{B_n} f \varphi_n = \int f \overline{\varphi_n} \le A$. So $\int_{B_n} f \operatorname{sgn} f \le A + \varepsilon$ and thus $\|f\|_1 \le A + \varepsilon < \infty$. This completes the proof.